# Pass custom values in MobileConnect API request

Tags: rest-api, api, mobileconnect, triggered-send

Is it possible to pass a custom value in a messageContact API request so that it's recorded with the send in the system generated SMS Send Log, assuming the send log has the custom field as part of its schema?

Example:

```
POST https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/KEY/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    "12223334444"
  ],
  "Subscribe": false,
  "Resubscribe": false,
  "Override": true,
  "Keyword": "JOIN",
  "message_name": "Welcome"
  "messageText": "Welcome to Code@"
}
```

In this example I'm looking to pass the value for 'message_name' to the SMS SendLog. While the example above executes in Postman, I'm not seeing any value recorded for 'message_name.'

My experience with APIs in general isn't extensive, so thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These additional JSON attributes would not be recorded to the sendlog. You would need to pass the message of the SMS and include these as variables in the message.

Your message body would be something like:

```
%%[ 
set @message_name = 'Welcome" set @messagetext = 'Welcome to code@"
]%%

%%=v(@messagetext)=%%
```

If your SMS send log had fields labeled message_name and messagetext the values would be saved to the sendlog

Comment: Does this work with TXM SMS sends as well?